# Migrating from MariaDB to Mysql - Duplicate Constraint Name

Tags: mysql, mariadb, migration, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to migrate from MariaDB to MySQL by doing a `mysqldump` from MariaDB and then restoring it to MySQL (`mysql:latest` docker container).

I am getting the following error when importing into MySQL:

```
ERROR 3822 (HY000) at line 172: Duplicate check constraint name 'CONSTRAINT_1'.
```

If I look at the mysqldump file I can see why this is happening. All boolean columns in my database have a constraints that looks something like:

```
CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` CHECK (`bool_col_1` in (0,1))
CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_2` CHECK (`bool_col_2` in (0,1))
CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_3` CHECK (`bool_col_3` in (0,1))
```

These constraints were not explicitly created by me but implicitly by Flask-SQLAlchemy (I think).

Notice how the constraint names are incremented starting with CONSTRAINT_1. Well the problem is that each table starts incrementing its constraint names starting with CONSTRAINT_1. Thus the error I am seeing gets thrown when trying to create the second table. According to the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html), duplicate constraint names are not allowed. Apparently MariaDB allows them.

**Is there a way to rename these constraints systematically or an alternative way to migrate the data?**

The quantity of tables prohibits manually changing the name of each constraint.

Note: [This fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGv5iw2FaXiMMRBVV1czkF/0) tests duplicate constraint names and executes without error on MySQL. However if I run the same commands on a fresh MySQL container, it fails with the duplicate constraint.

Comment: *Is there a way to rename these constraints systematically* Of course. For example, create your own pattern. It can be, for example, `CONSTRAINT_tablename_digit`...

Comment: @Akina - Perhaps I should have clarified. There are a large number of table that have these constraints such that manually changing them is not a reasonable option. Is there a way to rename them without manually changing each one?

Comment: There is no such service in MySQL. But you may parse dump file, find all CREATE TABLE statements and rename their constraints.